# full fenders on a track bike

Tags: fenders

I recently purchased a Fuji Track Classic bicycle. It's meant to be my commuter bike.

I was resigned to using a clip-on fender, but when I looked more closely it appeared that there should be room to mount full fenders on the frame. There's lots of clearance. The front for even has mounting points for a fender.

Is there any guideline for clearance that I should be conscious of? Does it look like it will work?

[image: front clearance]
[image: rear clearance]

Comment: You just need clearance.  Keep in mind that common plastic fenders will tend to twist to one side or the other by, perhaps, 5mm, so you need that much "extra" clearance between fender and the side of the tire.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I have about 2cm all around. I guess I'm good. Maybe I should give it a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly does look like you have ample clearance for fenders.

Those look long deep drop brake calipers too.

If you don't have fender mounts on the rear - you can always use P-Clips.